# How to get the serial number of the hard disk using Win API on Lua

Tags: api, winapi, lua, hard-drive

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
  int __stdcall GetVolumeInformationA(
  const char* lpRootPathName,
  char* lpVolumeNameBuffer,
  uint32_t nVolumeNameSize,
  uint32_t* lpVolumeSerialNumber,
  uint32_t* lpMaximumComponentLength,
  uint32_t* lpFileSystemFlags,
  char* lpFileSystemNameBuffer,
  uint32_t nFileSystemNameSize
);
]]
local serial = ffi.new("unsigned long[1]", 0)
ffi.C.GetVolumeInformationA(nil, nil, 0, serial, nil, nil, nil, 0)
serial1 = serial[0]
```

This will give the serial number of the logical drive, I need to get the serial number of the hard drive. How can I get it?

Comment: There are numerous questions on StackOverflow regarding how to retrieve the serial number you want.

Comment: I need to make a license check by serial number for the script. I'm not interested in other ways.

Comment: that does not change what I said.

Answer (score 0):

`wmic` is not part of WinAPI, but it gives more simple solution:

```
local function get_HDD0_serial()
   local pipe = io.popen"wmic diskdrive where(index=0) get serialnumber /value"
   local serial = (pipe:read"*a":match"SerialNumber=([^\r\n]*)" or ""):match"^(.-)%s*$"
   pipe:close()
   return serial
end

print(get_HDD0_serial())
```

If you want only WinAPI solution, you can rewrite it using `getWmiQueryResult`

Comment: Thats cool. Thank you. But i have another issue. The script works in full-screen application. After performing io.popen, it is minimized. Is it possible to make it work in the background?

Comment: @Darexu - Not in pure Lua.  Probably, you really need FFI to access `getWmiQueryResult` (or some other WinAPI function).