# Is it possible to get information about an external drive in Lua?

Tags: lua, drive, usb-drive

I was wondering if it was possible to get the information of a drive such as the capacity, drive letter, serial number and if the drive is an external one and other such info in Lua? I couldn't find any information about this. The closest thing I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55273463/how-to-get-the-serial-number-of-the-hard-disk-using-win-api-on-lua) way of getting the serial number of a drive using the Windows API (I think). Is their any way to getting this drive information without using any platform specific API? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not - https://lunarmodules.github.io/luafilesystem/

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I still have many possible uses for this library. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: No, not using the standard library. Lua's standard library is minimalistic. You'll have to use platform-specific APIs (which you may access using `os.execute`, `io.popen`, or simply files) or involve external libraries that do.